# Float: Left with different display types

Tags: html, css

I am just learning some more about displays and floats, and noticed that when I apply a float left to all display types, they then all behave like a display: inline-block.

This is a jsfiddle without the float left:

https://jsfiddle.net/j3jjpaxr/

And here is one with the float left:

https://jsfiddle.net/xhhbgsu1/

CSS:

```
.first {
    background-color: #435671;
}

.second {
    background-color: #135671;
}

.third {
    background-color: #935671;
}

.inlineblock {
    display: inline-block;
}

.inline {
    display: inline;
}

.block {
    display:block;
}

.testDiv {
    text-align: center;
    float:left;
    width: 33%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Can anyone explain why this happens, I would have expected the inline elements to at least keep their size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For inline elements the width is ignored (MDN: "An inline element occupies only the space bounded by the tags that define the inline element.")

Also from MDN:

> As float implies the use of the block layout, it modifies the computed
>   value of the display values in some cases:
>
> Specified value: inline
>
> Computed value: block
>
> ...

Thins means that when you set a `float` to an inline element, it's `display` value is forced to `block`. That's why you get the effect you described in your question.

https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/CSS/float
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements

Comment: Thanks - that's really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

It is not behaving like `inline-block`.

`inline-block` elements have a default spacing between them. Check your first fiddle.

`float` makes it behave like `block` element, which floats either left or right.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice that lack of spacing there. That makes a lot of sense that it's acting like a block element

Comment: @KevinWatson Block elements break lines, floated one's doesn't, unless they are too wide to fit the width of course.

Answer (score 2):

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from
>   the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its
>   container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it.

Src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

This simply means that an element, inline or block, behaves like a inline block but without the white space an inline element has.